# How can I make a row getting deleted if an update fails (for merging user accounts)?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am currently thinking about how to merge two user accounts.

I would simply go through all tables that might be affected and update the `user_id`. But for some rows, there are constraints (uniqueness; e.g. one user may cast only one vote in `wm_votes`).

**I want that either the UPDATE-query succeeds or the row that should get updated gets deleted instead.** How can I make that?

The following code is what I am currently thinking of:

```
/**
 * This method merges two user accounts.
 * The caller has to make super-sure that they are really the same users!
 * This step cannot be undone!
 * @param  int $ip_id      ID of an IP-User (gets deleted)
 * @param  int $regular_id ID of an NON-IP User (remains)
 * @return int             0 if everything is fine, something else otherwise
 */
function merge_accounts($ip_id, $regular_id) {
    global $pdo;
    $ip_id = int($ip_id);
    $regular_id = int($regular_id);
    $tables = array('wm_flags', 'wm_formula_svg_missing',
                    'wm_raw_data2formula', 'wm_raw_draw_data', 'wm_renderings',
                    'wm_user_unknown_formula', 'wm_votes', 'wm_workers');
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $sql = "UPDATE `$table` ".
               "SET `user_id` =  '$regular_id' WHERE `user_id` =$ip_id;";
        $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a `PROCEDURE` with transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Transactions and solve your possible constraint - problems before you update.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there is not better solution than

```
/**
 * This method merges two user accounts.
 * The caller has to make super-sure that they are really the same!
 * @param  int $ip_id      ID of an IP-User (gets deleted)
 * @param  int $regular_id ID of an NON-IP User (remains)
 * @return int             0 if everything is fine, something else otherwise
 */
function merge_accounts($ip_id, $regular_id) {
    global $pdo;
    $ip_id = int($ip_id);
    $regular_id = int($regular_id);

    // This approach might fail due to uniqueness constraints
    $tables = array('wm_flags', 'wm_formula_svg_missing',
                    'wm_raw_data2formula', 'wm_raw_draw_data', 'wm_renderings',
                    'wm_user_unknown_formula', 'wm_votes', 'wm_workers');
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $sql = "UPDATE `$table` ".
               "SET `user_id` =  '$regular_id' WHERE `user_id` =$ip_id;";
        $pdo->query($sql);
    }

    // Take a look at every dataset, try to change it and delete it if changing
    // wasn't successfull
    $tables = array('wm_flags', 'wm_formula_svg_missing',
                    'wm_raw_data2formula', 'wm_raw_draw_data', 'wm_renderings',
                    'wm_user_unknown_formula', 'wm_votes', 'wm_workers');
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `$table` WHERE `user_id` = $ip_id;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $flag_ids = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($flag_ids as $data) {
            $id = $data['id'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET `user_id` = $ip_id WHERE id=$id;";
            $result = $pdo->query($sql);
            if ($result === false) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM `$table` ".
                       "WHERE `id`=$id AND `user_id`=$ip_id LIMIT 1;";
                $pdo->query($sql);
            }
        }
    }

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `wm_users` WHERE `id`=$ip_id LIMIT 1;";
    $pdo->query($sql);

    return 0;
}
```